# Adding dynamic styles names for cell of celltable in gwt

Tags: gwt

I have a cell table with 3 column one for name, one for type and one for image.

I have another list box specifying a the types present in type column of cell table.

In cell table types may be same for more than one row.When I select a type in list box then all the rows in cell table which don't have same type should have an icon added in the image cell.

Till now I could search for adding style names dynamically depending on value entered in that cell itself. But now my intention is to have dynamic style name depending on value of another widget.

Please provide me with an answer. Below is the code provided

```
public class CellTableExample implements EntryPoint, ChangeHandler {

  CellTable<NameType> ct = new CellTable<NameType>();
  TextColumn<NameType> nameColumn;
  ListBox typeListBox = new ListBox();

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    typeListBox.addChangeHandler(this);
    nameColumn = new TextColumn<NameType>() {
      @Override
      public String getValue(NameType object) {
        return object.getName();
      }
    };
    ct.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");

    TextColumn<NameType> name1Column = new TextColumn<NameType>() {
      @Override
      public String getValue(NameType object) {
        return object.getType();
      }
    };
    ct.addColumn(name1Column, "Name1");

    List<NameType> values = new ArrayList<NameType>();

    NameType nameType1 = new NameType("name1", "type1");

    NameType nameType2 = new NameType("name2", "type2");

    values.add(nameType1);
    values.add(nameType2);
    ct.setRowData(values);

    ct.setLoadingIndicator(null);
    typeListBox.addItem("type1");
    typeListBox.addItem("type2");
    HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
    hp.add(typeListBox);
    hp .add(ct);


    RootPanel.get().add(hp);
  }

  @Override
  public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
    String type = typeListBox.getValue(typeListBox.getSelectedIndex());
    int rowCount = ct.getRowCount();

    for(int i=0;i < rowCount; i++) {
      String value = ct.getRowElement(i).getCells().getItem(1).getInnerText();

      if(type.equals(value)) {
        Window.alert("came here");
        TableCellElement cellElement = ct.getRowElement(i).getCells().getItem(0);
        cellElement.addClassName("information icon");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In `onChange()` method that is the logic that I thought for adding classname depending on selection in listbox. But i am looking for more generic solution :)

Comment: Its very tough to get the exact question from the above description.Can you please post some code ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to manipulate the content of the cells after they have been rendered by the table. However I have an idea which is not that nice but feasible: render some id's or custom HTML attributes into your cells so that you can later access them via standard but quite un-GWT DOM manipulations:

```
<td><img src=".." id="icon-of-entity-123" /></td>
```

And if you achieve something like this, then later in your business logic, even after rendering you can manipulate it on low-level:

```
Element e = DOM.getElementById("icon-of-entity-" + getId());
e.setAttribute("class", "someclassname");
```

I wish that someone gave you a better solution!